# GWT - Graphical representation of a tree

Tags: gwt, tree, graphic

I want to represent a Tree in my GWt Project in a another way as the standard graphical
representation.
Drag & Drop should be able.
Like this one:
http://s1.directupload.net/file/d/2603/yzo588bb_jpg.htm

Do you know a good GWT Extension to realize this?
I have already looked at the Google Web Toolkit Gallery.
Do you think something like this would solve the problem?
http://gwtgallery.appspot.com/about_app?app_id=86

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using Raphaël Gwt for such graphic stuff.
I've tried Vectomatic once, but it is no fun to write, because it seems like the author had no Idea what a namespace is (Several classes starting with OMSVG) and it doesn't "feel" like writing a java programm.

On the other side, with Raphël-GWT is a binding to a javascript-library, thus you have (llittle) Preformance tradeoff for loading an external Cross-browser javascript library.

Comment: And what about drag & drop with Raphaël Gwt?

Comment: that's nasty, you're right but possible (mousedown-, mousemove- and mouseup handler are the one way, the other is to extend (read do some really nasty JSNI stuff in the library) the bindings because Raphaël (the js lib) has some drag and drop built in, but that isn't very javaish (you have to supply some callback functions))

Comment: @ph09: unfortunatley not, I'm sorry, that are the only two libraries I've worked with; there is another library- gwt-graphics - around, but you have to sign in to download the sources.